# Typography in landing page

Tags: design-process, prototype, typography, landing-page

I'm working on a landing page . The first view shows a major title with a great source ( Roboto : 190px ) and a diagonal line . Is it a good practice to use a large font for a good experience with that design ?

This is a prototype . I should add that this photo was taken from a 1366x768 screen :

[image]

Comment: This isn't a UX question. It' a graphic design question so should be asked there. And it needs a lot more context for it to produce truly helpful feedback.

Answer (score 1):

A landing page is only useful if it has some sort of purpose.  Usually landing pages exist for people who come to the site through a certain route (such as clicking on an ad), and they display content relevant to that route of entering the site.

Without a purpose, a landing page will simply annoy users who have to click and load an extra page to get to your actual site.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents on the issue: Large, prominent fonts only look good on banners and bumper stickers!

If you look at ads by Apple, Samsung & Google, they resort to leaving a lot of blank space and using medium size, clean font. Due to the white space, the focus automatically shifts to the text.

**For Example:**

[image]

[image]

[Have a look at this article to better understand what I'm trying to convey.](http://www.cultofmac.com/179202/what-the-world-would-look-like-if-apple-designed-every-ad-gallery/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that extra large fonts distract the users. Usually a landing page contains information that you want users to view but if the user is distracted by an unusually large font and bold colours, it becomes hard to get your message across.